How to keep pandas read_csv from numbering identical values in a row of a DataFrame?
I just came across some issue which has seemingly not been discussed in python forums or in any tutorials. At least, I couldn't find any explanation.
I want to use Python/pandas to read a csv file line by line and write (append) the lines to another csv file.
Don't wonder why I'm doing this: I want to modify a very large csv file (row number >> 10000) row by row and have also to insert additional new rows if needed...
Here my minimal example, which may show what I mean:
import csv
import pandas as pd

# get total number of rows
file_content = pd.read_csv('test_read.csv')
row_count = len(file_content)

i = 0
while i <= row_count:
    # read DataFrame with single line from input file
    df = pd.read_csv('test_read.csv', skiprows=lambda x: x!=i, sep=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    # write DataFrame to output file
    df.to_csv('test_out.csv', mode='a', sep=';', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    i = i + 1

The contents of the input file "test_read.csv", as shown by Notepad++:
"Pos 1";"96";"0";"0";"ABCDEF";"5.67";"0.0";"ABCDEF";"0";"0"
"Pos 2";"34";"0";"0";"GHIJKL";"5.53";"0.0";"OPQRST";"0";"0"
After running the python code, the output file "test_out.csv" contains:
"Pos 1";"96";"0";"0".1;"ABCDEF";"5.67";"0.0";"ABCDEF".1;"0".2;"0".3
"Pos 2";"34";"0";"0".1;"GHIJKL";"5.53";"0.0";"OPQRST";"0".2;"0".3
As can be seen, the four recurring "0" values in each row got some sort of index numbers .1, .2 and .3 appended, except of the first one. Same with the "ABCDEF" string in the first row. All others are not affected.
When I remove skiprows=lambda x: x!=i in reading the DataFrame df, this "numbering" of recurring strings does not happen at all.
When reading several rows in one DataFrame, only the first row of each DataFrame is affected by this "numbering":
"Pos 1";"96";"0";"0".1;"ABCDEF";"5.67";"0.0";"ABCDEF".1;"0".2;"0".3
"Pos 2";"34";"0";"0";"GHIJKL";"5.53";"0.0";"OPQRST";"0";"0"
"Pos 3";"27";"0";"0";"GHIJKL";"4.12";"0.0";"GHIJKL";"0";"0"
"Pos 4";"49";"0";"0".1;"GHIJKL";"3.89";"0.0";"OPQRST";"0".2;"0".3
"Pos 5";"71";"0";"0";"KLMNOP";"4.40";"0.0";"KLMNOP";"0";"0"
"Pos 6";"52";"0";"0";"STUVWX";"6.72";"0.0";"STUVWX";"0";"0"
In this 6 line example, I canged to skiprows=lambda x: x not in [i, i+1, i+2] and i = i + 3 to read 3 rows per DataFrame. Only the 1st and the 4th rows are affected.
I assume it might come from my usage of skiprows. Is there an alternative way to read a csv file line by line (using pandas), which might not show this "numbering" behavior?
The output file shall be read by another software, which refuses to read it including the appended "numbers".
Any help to get rid of them is highly appreciated...

Or see this post. Your title has "numbering identical values in a row of a DataFrame". But they are not in a row. By default, pd.read_csv will interpret the first line as column labels. Try print(df.columns) and you'll see. To avoid this, use header=None. If you have duplicate headers, pd.read_csv will automatically add a suffix (.1, .2). to distinguish between them. Hence: "0", "0".1, "0".2, "0".3.

Incidentally, it looks like you need csv.QUOTE_ALL rather than csv.QUOTE_NONE.

Ok, I already came across of both posts you linked, and indeed they suggest the same solution header=None. I just didn't realize that this might be the solution for me as well, because I very much focussed on these suffixes, which were not explicitely mentioned. But thanks a lot for these hints.

I copied the csv.QUOTE_NONE from some code example to remove double quotation in the output file. But you're right: csv.QUOTE_ALL gives the very same result.

I answered the question, whether the post Python Pandas does not read the first row of csv file answers my question, with "Yes", because the header=None solution fixes my issue. But I would never have realized this by myself, because the focus of this post was different and didn't include the issue of appended suffixes.

If I understand you correctly, you need to add header=None parameter when you read/write the CSV:
import csv

import pandas as pd

# get total number of rows
file_content = pd.read_csv("test_read.csv")
row_count = len(file_content)

i = 0
while i <= row_count:
    # read DataFrame with single line from input file
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "test_read.csv", skiprows=lambda x: x != i, sep=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None
    )
    # write DataFrame to output file
    df.to_csv("test_out.csv", mode="a", sep=";", index=False, header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    i = i + 1

Then the output file contains:
"Pos 1";"96";"0";"0";"ABCDEF";"5.67";"0.0";"ABCDEF";"0";"0"
"Pos 2";"34";"0";"0";"GHIJKL";"5.53";"0.0";"OPQRST";"0";"0"


That's done it! I really didn't relate header=None to these "numbers, because I thought it would have only effect on reading the header rows. Wow, what a simple and quick answer to my question! You made my day...
